# Reader of Pipe Doesn't See EOF or EOS

Tags: c

In this function, how do I make it so that the parent stops trying to read from the pipe. I.e. if I run the command ls | grep test grep won't output `test` and `test.c` and then wait for user input?

```
pipe(pipefd);

int pid = fork();
if (pid != 0) {
    dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    int rv2 = execv(get_contain_dir(command_to), args_to);
    close(pipefd[0]);
} else {
    dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    int rv1 = execv(get_contain_dir(command_from), args_from);
    close(pipefd[1]);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better what are you trying to achieve? Do you want that the standard OUTPUT of the parent is redirect to the standard INPUT of the child? ( you should add the tag linux)

Comment: I'm trying to emulate console piping within c. whatever is executed in the parent's output is piped into the child (via STDOUT/STDIN). The above code runs, and pipes fine, but it doesn't seem to want to *close* the pipe. That is, after "grep" in my original example, the command "stays open" accepting input from the user. 

As I have is running right now, it completely exits my program (which is also wrong).

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing the pipes correctly. Each process must close the pipe that it does not use :

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid != 0) {
    dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(pipefd[1]); // not using the left side
    int rv2 = execv(get_contain_dir(command_to), args_to);

} else {
    dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipefd[0]);  // not using the right side 
    int rv1 = execv(get_contain_dir(command_from), args_from);
}
```